# PHP - Find and replace enclosed text in an external HTML file

Tags: php, html, str-replace

I have a PHP file that renders an HTML file, inside this HTML file I have this piece of code

```
<div class="app">{: echo $this->content :}</div>
```

And I want to replace the opening `{:` and closing `:}` tags with the traditional `<?php ?>` tags to make it look something like this:

```
<div class="app"><?php echo $this->content ?></div>
```

Comment: And so what have you tried?

Comment: If there are any collisions with text being `:}`/`{:` then you could use something like `str_replace(...)`.

Comment: load html to string, and do http://php.net/str_replace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$contents = file_get_contents ("file.php");
$contents = str_replace(array('{:', ':}'), array('<?php', '?>'), $contents);
file_put_contents("file.php", $contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a simple string replace if you are doing this within PHP

`str_replace(array('{:', ':}'), array('<?php', '?>'), $file_content)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$string = '<div class="app">{: echo $this->content :}</div>';
$string = str_replace('{:','<?php',$string);
$string = str_replace(':}','?>',$string);
```

If you want to catch the content inside the  you can use this :

```
$string = '<div class="app">{: echo $this->content :}</div>';
preg_match('/<div class="app">(.+)<\/div>/',$string,$preg_array);
$string = str_replace('{:','<?php',$preg_array[1]);
$string = str_replace(':}','?>',$string);
```

Output :

```
<?php echo $this->content ?>
```